# Why does my PHP error log show only brackets?

Tags: php, error-log

I'm wondering if anyone knows why my error_log shows entries that are simply "{}"... nothing else. The error log file shows other warnings as well, but many entries look like the below.

For example: "[30-Apr-2021 21:06:14 UTC] {}"

Has anyone seen this before and can maybe point me in the right direction? This is a LAMP environment running WordPress.

Thank you!

Comment: which error log, its unclear which LAMP component you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, it's the PHP error log

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information instead of answering in comments. I suggest to show which files you have and which one contains the strange messages. Do you mean that **all** messages in the file look like the example in the question or that the file contains **some** messages of this type? What PHP programs do you run?

Comment: Updated... I couldn't find the edit link, thanks for providing one. The file is just a PHP error log, nothing special to it. I provided the log example in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @heathhettig I am having the same issue. Did you find out what it was?